# query not adding to table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, bootstrap-4, webforms

I am new to web forms and am trying to add value from the front end aspx page to my sql  table . However I am not able to add it to the table. It is printing  all prompt values except the last one after ExecuteNonQuery(). It is also not printing the exception. it is showing no prompt.

Here is the code in the CS file:

```
namespace LibraryManagementSystem
{
    public partial class Usersignup : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //sign up button click event
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Testing');</script>");
           
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
                if(con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }

                Response.Write("<script>alert('Connection');</script>");

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.member_master_tbl(full_name,dob,contact_no,email,state,city,pincode," +
                    "full_address,member_id,password,account_status) values" +
                    "(@full_name,@dob,@contact_no,@email,@state,@city,@pincode," +
                    "@full_address,@member_id,@password,@account_status) ", con);

                Response.Write("<script>alert('Query');</script>");

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@full_name", Textbox3.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@dob", Textbox2.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@contact_no", Textbox1.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@email", Textbox4.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@state", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@city", Textbox6.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@pincode", Textbox7.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@full_address", Textbox5.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@member_id", Textbox8.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@password", Textbox9.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@account_status", "pending");

                Response.Write("<script>alert('Table');</script>");

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Sign Up Successful. Go to User Login to Login');</script>");


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
            }



        }
    }
}
```

It is printing all the response values before execute non query

I dont understand why it is not printing the last 2 responses. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is, when you are adding parameter values, you have an open parenthesis before the "@" in each parameter name, so when the query gets executed, it's throwing an exception, fails to insert the record in the database table, and fails to send that last response.  Replace that paragraph of your code with this (removed the open parenthesis on each line):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", Textbox3.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", Textbox2.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_no", Textbox1.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Textbox4.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", Textbox6.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pincode", Textbox7.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_address", Textbox5.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@member_id", Textbox8.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Textbox9.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_status", "pending");
```

As for why the response in the "catch" block isn't being sent, the exception message may have some characters in it that are being interpreted as JavaScript.  Since your call to "alert" is using single quotes, if the message returned by the exception also contains any single quotes in it, that will terminate the string being passed to the alert, and everything after that quote will be looked at as JavaScript.